# How to send a batch request use Retrofit

Tags: gmail, retrofit, gmail-api

I want to read emails by Gmail API using retrofit, but I faced a problem when I want to send a batch request(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) to fetch multi mails. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem is I can not construct a batch request like the sample from Google. I searched for a project achieve this, but I failed.